# suppress the margin of R plots vertically

Tags: r, plot

I am using base R plot function to generate vertically aligned plots (2-by-1), with both x and y labels but without a title. However, when I use

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
plot(obj1)
plot(obj2)
```

I notice that the blank margin area between the two plots is so huge (I assume R does not exclude the area for the `main=` title...). Is there a way to make the two plots more "closer" to each other, while keep the x-labels at appropriate locations?

BTW, is there a way to generate a plot in PDF format without any useless blank margins? I plan to include the figure in the paper manuscript, and I don't want to see such margins occupying. Thanks!

Comment: @joran: thanks, but how can I address the first question, i.e. the blank margin between the two plots that aligned vertically?

Comment: By adjusting the margins, as indicated in the question I linked to. Have you read it or tried it yet?

Comment: @joran: yes, thanks for the post. I tried to control the outer margin, but still cannot figure out how to control the area between the two vertical plots...

Comment: I'm not sure how else to say it. You adjust the margins by setting `par(mar = ...)` as needed. Edit your question to include exactly what you tried.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As described in the (duplicate) question I linked to, the solution is exactly the same as there:

```
par(mfrow=c(2,1))
par(mar = c(0,4,4,2) + 0.1)
plot(1:5)
par(mar = c(5,4,0,2) + 0.1)
plot(1:5)
```

[image]